# Tar: Extract only files (not sub-directories)

Tags: tar

How do I extract **only** files from a directory in a tar archive? I need to extract all the files in the directory, not specific files.
For example, with a tar archive of this structure:

```
wordpress
 --wp-admin
 --wp-content
 --wp-includes
 --index.php
 --license.txt
 --readme.html
```

I want to extract only the 3 (or more) files in the wordpress directory not the sub-directories.

Note that the other solutions I could find on this site are about extracting specific files. My question is about extracting *all* files.

Comment: could there be folders with `.` in their names within the archive (like `folder.suff`)?

Comment: Good question. I think the --no-wildcards-match-slash option prevents any sub-directories from being matched. I haven't tested this, so I can't confirm it, though.

Comment: @ChetanCrasta, I've tested those options `--wildcards --no-wildcards-match-slash` and they do not prevent subdirectories extraction at all

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work with subdirectories of type folder.name? Or with all sub-directories?
I can confirm that the solution given works on Debian.

Comment: you want to extract specific files -- the ones that aren't subdirectories; does the `--files-from` option not work for you? You'd list the contents of the tar file, then filter for only the wordpress folder, then exclude the sub-folders, then pass that file to tar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I can make an assumption about the format of directory names and file names, I can't find any way of extracting files at a particular level without also extracting (empty) directories at that same level. (If file names contain a dot but directories do not, then [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370363/100397) will be sufficient.)

Consider `370358.tar` with this content

```
wordpress/
wordpress/index.php
wordpress/license.txt
wordpress/readme.html
wordpress/wp-admin/
wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php
wordpress/wp-content/
wordpress/wp-content/2021/
wordpress/wp-content/2021/01/
wordpress/wp-content/2021/01/19/
wordpress/wp-content/2021/01/19/today.txt
wordpress/wp-content/content.txt
wordpress/wp-content/here.txt
wordpress/wp-content/some.txt
wordpress/wp-includes/
```

You can extract files matching `wordpress/*` like this

```
tar xf /tmp/370358.tar --wildcards --exclude '*/*/*' && rmdir */* 2>/dev/null

ls -R wordpress
wordpress:
index.php  license.txt  readme.html
```

Notice the trailing `rmdir`. We cannot tell `tar` to skip directory creation even though the resulting directories will be empty, so we simply delete them afterwards.

If you don't actually want the `wordpress` directory to be included in the extraction,

```
tar xf /tmp/370358.tar --strip-components 1 --wildcards --exclude '*/*/*' && rmdir * 2>/dev/null

ls -R
.:
index.php  license.txt  readme.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU `tar`, you could extract the archive through a short `bash` script:

```bsh
tar -x -f archive.tar --to-command=./script.sh
```

... where `script.sh` is the executable script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$TAR_FILETYPE" = f ] &&
   [[ $TAR_FILENAME == wordpress/* ]] &&
   [[ $TAR_FILENAME != wordpress/*/* ]]
then
    mkdir -p "${TAR_FILENAME%/*}" &&
    cat >"$TAR_FILENAME" &&
    chmod "$TAR_MODE" "$TAR_FILENAME" &&
    chown "$TAR_UNAME:$TAR_GNAME" "$TAR_FILENAME" || true
else
    cat >/dev/null
fi
```

The `TAR_*` variables used here are set in the script's environment by GNU `tar`, and the data of the file currently being extracted is arriving over standard input.

The tests used in the script is to make sure that

1. The file we're extracting is a regular file, and
2. The file is located in the `wordpress` directory and nowhere else.

To extract a file, we simply make sure that the file's directory exists, redirect the standard input to the correct filename, and then modify the file mode and ownerships so that the permissions and owners are correct.

You could obviously also give the script in-line on the `tar` command line:

```bsh
tar -x -f archive.tar --to-command='bash -c "
    if [ \"\$TAR_FILETYPE\" = f ] &&
       [[ \$TAR_FILENAME == wordpress/* ]] &&
       [[ \$TAR_FILENAME != wordpress/*/* ]]
    then
        mkdir -p \"\${TAR_FILENAME%/*}\" &&
        cat >\"\$TAR_FILENAME\" &&
        chmod \"\$TAR_MODE\" \"\$TAR_FILENAME\" &&
        chown \"\$TAR_UNAME:\$TAR_GNAME\" \"\$TAR_FILENAME\" || true
    else
        cat >/dev/null
    fi"'
```

Answer (score -1):

This will extract all the files in a directory in a tar file, without going into the sub-directories:

```
tar --wildcards --no-wildcards-match-slash -xvf file.tar.gz directory_in_tar/*.*
```

Comment: Works beautifully provided that no directory contains a dot, and that all required file names do have one. (In order words, the `*.*` is the glob that determines what can and cannot be extracted.)

Comment: Good catch. Thanks!